# How to load arbitrary config file via git?

Tags: git

I'm trying to load a config file in git, but the file is not in one of the default storage locations. I tried doing `git config --file .gitconfig` (when I was in the correct directory that contains the `.gitconfig` file) but git responded by giving me a standard help message. i.e.:

```
usage: git config [options]

Config file location
    --global              use global config file
    --system              use system config file
    --local               use repository config file
    -f, --file <file>     use given config file

etc.
```

Comment: Have you `tried ./.gitconfig` ?

Comment: No - I can't imagine why that would work, but I suppose I can try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want to do:

```
$ git config --local include.path "$PWD/.gitconfig"
```

This will include the local `.gitconfig` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that as your global config file, copy it to your home directory:

```
cp .gitconfig ~/
```

It looks like setting the file for `git config` command is for the case when you want to `--get` a particular setting.